# If Statement to check multiple columns and return a value for a new column

Tags: r, if-statement

I have matrix containing four columns and another matrix containing the same four columns. The first one has the daily max amount for every year and the month and day it occurred. The second one has a year, month, and day in which a tropical cyclone passed near my site and the maximum rainfall it caused (SI_SP_MAX). I want to create a fifth column in rain.max that relates the maximums. I want this column to consist of 0's and 1's. 1 would represent if the tropical cyclone caused the daily max of the given year and 0 if it did not. I tried doing this with an if else statement, but the fifth column only contained 0's.  I need the Year, Month, and Day to be checked and do not know how to go about this.
The first few rows of data are:

rain.max

```
     Year Month Day Max_mm
     1941     1   4   86.4
     1942     2  11  115.8
     1943     3   5  148.3
     1944     3   8   61.5
     1945     1   9   61.7
```

SI_SP_MAX

```
      Year Month Day Max_mm Basin
      1942     2  11  115.8    SI
      1943     3   5  148.3    SI
      1944     3   8   61.5    SI
      1948     4  11  106.9    SI
      1953     1   2  105.4    SI
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility:

First we use `merge` to match the information:

```
temp <- merge(rain.max, SI_SP_MAX, by=c("Year", "Month", "Day"), all.x=TRUE)
#  Year Month Day Max_mm.x Max_mm.y Basin
#1 1941     1   4     86.4       NA  <NA>
#2 1942     2  11    115.8    115.8    SI
#3 1943     3   5    148.3    148.3    SI
#4 1944     3   8     61.5     61.5    SI
#5 1945     1   9     61.7       NA  <NA>
```

Then we compare the columns:

```
rain.max$cyclone <- temp$Max_mm.x == temp$Max_mm.y
rain.max$cyclone[is.na(rain.max$cyclone)] <- FALSE
#  Year Month Day Max_mm cyclone
#1 1941     1   4   86.4   FALSE
#2 1942     2  11  115.8    TRUE
#3 1943     3   5  148.3    TRUE
#4 1944     3   8   61.5    TRUE
#5 1945     1   9   61.7   FALSE
```

If you like, you can transform the logical values into integers afterwards, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: >Thank you, I did use the merge function. But I did it differently. >colnames(SI_SP_MAX)=c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Max_mm_x", "Basin")
>temp= merge(rain.max, SI_SP_MAX, by=c("Year", "Month", "Day"), all=TRUE)
>temp$Basin[is.na(temp$Basin)] = 0
>temp[,7]=1
>colnames(temp)=c("Year", "Month", "Day","Max_mm", "Max_TC", "Basin", "TC")
>temp$TC[is.na(temp$Max_TC)] = 0

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site and do not know how to add it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rain.max <- structure(list(Year = 1941:1945, Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L
), Day = c(4L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 9L), Max_mm = c(86.4, 115.8, 148.3, 
61.5, 61.7)), .Names = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Max_mm"), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, -5L))

SI_SP_MAX <- structure(list(Year = c(1942L, 1943L, 1944L, 1948L, 1953L), Month = c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), Day = c(11L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 2L), Max_mm = c(115.8, 
148.3, 61.5, 106.9, 105.4), Basin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "SI", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", "Month", 
"Day", "Max_mm", "Basin"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

library(plyr)
subset(
   transform(
           join(rain.max, SI_SP_MAX, by=c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Max_mm"), type="left"),
              indx_max=(!is.na(Basin))+0), 
                              select=-Basin)
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(rain.max, SI_SP_MAX, by=c("Year","Month","Day", "Max_mm"))%>% 
mutate(indx_max=(!is.na(Basin))+0) %>%
select(-Basin)
```